# how to using fillna into original dataset from merge dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge, fillna

I have 2 different dataset

1 is master data with 400k row - big data

another one is 10k row - small data

let say df1 - big data

df2 - small data

I using loc for 1 id.

I don't want for column df1['ltl'] to be zero, so I want to replace it with column df2['os']

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
```

```
data = {'index' : [8,9,10,11,12,146131,146132,146133,146134,146135,199730,199731,199732,291350,291351,291352,318870,318871,318872,318873,318874],
        'id' : [1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411,1411],
        'ltl' :  [4358,5686,4180,0,5167,0,4358,5686,5167,4180,5167,4180,4358,5167,4358,4180,4358,5686,4180,0,5167],
        'year' : [2016,2019,2017,2020,2018,2020,2016,2019,2018,2017,2018,2017,2016,2018,2016,2017,2016,2019,2017,2020,2018]}
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1.set_index('index')
```

```
data2 = {'index2' : [1131,1132],
        'id' : [1411,1411],
        'os' :  [15760,3045],
        'year' : [2019,2020]}
```

```
df2 =pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2.set_index('index2')
```

so I merge these 2 data

```
mergei = df1.merge(df2, on=['id','year'], how='inner')
mergei.shape
mergei

mergei['ltl'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
mergei

mergei['ltl'].fillna(value=mergei['os'],inplace=True)
mergei
```

As you can see, I managed to fill column ['ltl'] in the merge data

If I try to bring the value from merge data to fill in df1['ltl'],
the result is like this

```
df1['ltl'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df1['ltl'].fillna(value=mergei['os'], inplace=True)
df1
```

```
    index   id  ltl year
0   8   1411    4358.0  2016
1   9   1411    5686.0  2019
2   10  1411    4180.0  2017
3   11  1411    **3045.0    2020**
4   12  1411    5167.0  2018
5   146131  1411    **3045.0    2020**
6   146132  1411    4358.0  2016
7   146133  1411    5686.0  2019
8   146134  1411    5167.0  2018
9   146135  1411    4180.0  2017
10  199730  1411    5167.0  2018
11  199731  1411    4180.0  2017
12  199732  1411    4358.0  2016
13  291350  1411    5167.0  2018
14  291351  1411    4358.0  2016
15  291352  1411    4180.0  2017
16  318870  1411    4358.0  2016
17  318871  1411    5686.0  2019
18  318872  1411    4180.0  2017
19  318873  1411    **NaN   2020**
20  318874  1411    5167.0  2018
```

as you can see, for line 19, i want to fill with 3045, but the index is not aline
I want to fill the value based on **ID and Year**

I try to reset_index on ID and it didnt work,

I also try combine_first and it didnt work.

if I work with merge data, then the shape is changes.
df1 is master data here.

I expected the result to be like this

```
    index   id  ltl year
0   8   1411    4358.0  2016
1   9   1411    5686.0  2019
2   10  1411    4180.0  2017
3   11  1411    **3045.0    2020**
4   12  1411    5167.0  2018
5   146131  1411    **3045.0    2020**
6   146132  1411    4358.0  2016
7   146133  1411    5686.0  2019
8   146134  1411    5167.0  2018
9   146135  1411    4180.0  2017
10  199730  1411    5167.0  2018
11  199731  1411    4180.0  2017
12  199732  1411    4358.0  2016
13  291350  1411    5167.0  2018
14  291351  1411    4358.0  2016
15  291352  1411    4180.0  2017
16  318870  1411    4358.0  2016
17  318871  1411    5686.0  2019
18  318872  1411    4180.0  2017
19  318873  1411    **3045.0    2020**
20  318874  1411    5167.0  2018
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can just change the inner join to left join  and reassign it back to df1. To make it safe, you can assign it to mergei and assign it back to master data df1 once you are sure the code works

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['id','year'], how='left')
df1['ltl'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True) 
df1['ltl'].fillna(value=mergei['os'], inplace=True)
df1[['index', 'id', 'ltl', 'year']]
```

Output:

```
    index   id      ltl     year
0   8       1411    4358.0  2016
1   9       1411    5686.0  2019
2   10      1411    4180.0  2017
3   11      1411    3045.0  2020
4   12      1411    5167.0  2018
5   146131  1411    3045.0  2020
6   146132  1411    4358.0  2016
7   146133  1411    5686.0  2019
8   146134  1411    5167.0  2018
9   146135  1411    4180.0  2017
10  199730  1411    5167.0  2018
11  199731  1411    4180.0  2017
12  199732  1411    4358.0  2016
13  291350  1411    5167.0  2018
14  291351  1411    4358.0  2016
15  291352  1411    4180.0  2017
16  318870  1411    4358.0  2016
17  318871  1411    5686.0  2019
18  318872  1411    4180.0  2017
19  318873  1411    3045.0  2020
20  318874  1411    5167.0  2018
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, i already try left merge, what happen is , it changed the shape of dataset, and i can replace and fillna ltl into merge dataset without any problem, but for the shape, im not sure how to identify which shape that is added, because the master data need to merge with other file.. i also try to insert the value from merge left to master data, and around 81 value did not fillna because the index of master data and index mergeleft is not align